# how to check if a specific folder exists in filedialog.askdirectory()

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem where I can't check if a specific folder exists in the `filedialog` path I want. I have tried a lot of solutions but none of them worked.

```py
from tkinter import *       
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

def Browse():
    find = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder.set(find)
    if find:
        os.path.isdir("Form Folder")
        print("Yess")
    else:
        print("cancelled")

form1 = Tk()
form1.title = "Check file"

folder = StringVar()

button = Button(form1, text="browse", command=Browse)
button.pack()

form1.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you please try to explain your desired outcome better?  It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: `askdirectory()` can only return already-existing folders. Why do you think you need to check if it exists? `os.path.isdir` is the right way to check, but in your code you're passing it something other than what the user picked.